# cassandra connector for loopback

Tags: cassandra, loopbackjs

I was looking for cassandra connector for loopback so that it creates the model and api. I cannot see a connector for the same in the loopback.

My question is how can I use the cassandra connector that is available for nodejs use in loopback in the same way as other model connectors are used in loopback.

Is there a way to integrate this connector in the loopback environment

Answer (score 0):

At this time there is not a loopback connector for Cassandra.  However, there is documentation [here](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Building+a+connector) on how to create your own connector if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra connector for LoopBack has arrived!

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/cassandra-connector-has-arrived/